# Is there a Java property to set the location of the CRL files instead of using CRL Distribution Point extension in X509 Certificate

Tags: java, pki, java-security, certificate-revocation

Is there a Java (JDK8) property that can be used to provide CRL support to point to a file or directory containing lists? I have looked into com.sun.net.checkRevocation and com.sun.security.enableCRLDP properties, and it appears that the certificates would need to have the CRL Distribution Point (CDP) extension to be able to use the second property. But our certificates are not guaranteed to have the CDP extension, and I am wondering if there is some other property in Java to specify the location of the CRL files, as in:
some.property.for.crl.location="/root/crl-dir".

Java has support to specify the OCSP responder URL in ocsp.responderURL property, it would be hard to image they don't have something similar for CRLs. But, all my searches on the net has only pointed me to CDP extension in the certificates, and I am turning to StackOverflow for some answers.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Usha

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ocsp.html#client-side-settings)?